# Rendering different content for each eye in Mixed Reality

Tags: xaml, windows-10-universal, windows-mixed-reality

I'm currently looking to see if there is a way that within a Windows 10 Universal App, that is intended for Mixed Reality, to display different content for each eye?

What would ideal is if this could be done entirely in XAML, for example...

```
<mixedreality target="lefteye">
  ...
</mixedreality>
<mixedreality target="righteye">
  ...
</mixedreality>
```

I know this can be done in a Unity App but I want this to be done within a Window in the Mixed Reality portal.

Thanks in advance.

Nick.

Comment: You can put two videos on both left and right side on a UWP Xaml. But UWP app by default does not provide any tag like 'mixedreality" you mentioned. You should use Unity to help you create your Mixed Reality app.

Comment: I've tried Unity too, that's a separate question I have open. I wanted to check if it could be done in XAML.

Comment: Using XAML can work with DirectX app as far as I know, here is the [reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using_xaml_with_holographic_directx_apps). But this is not what you want, right? I guess you just want to simply the developing so you are thinking about using XAML.

Comment: That's right, it can, but I'm trying to get control over what I decide to render for each eye, in a 2D mode app on Mixed reality. If you use the Holographic template for DX11, it shows it in full screen immersive mode, not as a pinnable 2D mode app in cliff House. I don't have any problem with full screen immersive app.

Comment: As far as I can tell, and unless there is some undocumented technique, you can't get references to each eye camera unless it's a full screen immersive app. The ability to do it in XAML like above would be super powerful.